# How to read values from a text file and then find and replace the value in a xml file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an .xml file - let's say A.xml. This file contains a "version node"

example:

```
<Root>
    <Version>2.5</Version>
</Root>
```

Now, I want to replace the value of version with a different number dynamically by reading from a .txt file which will have following content:

```
2.5 
3.5
```

It means I need to replace string of '2.5' with '3.5' in the A.xml.

***I need to accomplish with the help of window batch file(.bat) file.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
TYPE NUL>tempOutput.xml
SET line=0
SET from=
SET to=
FOR /F %%a IN (a.txt) DO (
    IF !line!==0 SET from=%%a
    IF !line!==1 SET to=%%a
    SET /a line=!line!+1
)
ECHO replacing %from% with %to%...
FOR /F %%a IN (a.xml) DO (
    SET currentLine=%%a
    SET currentLine=!currentLine:%from%=%to%!
    ECHO !currentLine!>>tempOutput.xml
)
DEL /q a.xml
MOVE tempOutput.xml a.xml
PAUSE
```

First, we create a temp file (tempOutput.xml). Then we read a.txt assuming that that it has only two lines, the first line contains the old version number and the second line the new one.

Now we read a.xml line by line and replace any appearance of the old version number with the new one and store the modified lines in our temp file.

Finally we delete the old file and replace it with the modified one renaming it from tempOutput.xml to a.xml.

EDIT: Yes, you can simplify the code and cut it shorter but I think this is easier to understand.

Comment: Micahels, thanks but what if we have n number of lines in .txt, in assumption we have only two lines, how to expand it to have multiple values, dyanmic variables,

Comment: or is it possible to loop through the two line at every loop, then using inner loop, loop through the text of .xml file and replace the values, So, we won't have to take n number of variables to store 'find' and 'replace' string.\

Comment: Simply adjust the lines IF !line!==x and insert the correct line number. You can also add new variables.